# A different cursor for each action

Tags: css, cursor

Is there a way to set another cursor for moving objects and, for example, another for resizing?

```
.dragme {
cursor: url("/images/cursor.png"), move !important; }
```

This css sets the cursor to my own image but for all actions like (dragging, n-resizing, moving) I need to have another cursor for dragging and another for resizing.

Answer (score 0):

may this can help you.. I think than using an svg image is more important

```
https://codyhouse.co/nuggets/custom-cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want diff cursors like when its upon your images or text , you can simply use css property `<img style="cursor:grab;" src="#" alt="#"></img>`

Answer (score 0):

There is still no answer to change it in a way I like . Cursor is changing but for every action.